# Why datagrid_data1.json data can not appear

Tags: php, jquery-easyui

In my project, i use easyui-datagrid.

Here is my html code:

```
  <tr>
      <td style="width:10%" colspan="2">attachment</td>
      <td style="width:90%" colspan="18">
         <table  class="easyui-datagrid" data-options="url:'datagrid_data1.json',method:'get'" title="" style="width:100%">
           <thead>
             <tr>
              <th data-options="field:'ck',checkbox:true"></th>
              <th data-options="field:'name',align:'center'">filename</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
         </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

The code of datagrid_data1.json:

```
{"total":2,"rows":[
{"name":"1.jpg"},
{"name":"123.jpg"}
]}
```

But unfortunately, I works fail. Two names of 1.jpg and 123.jpg can not appear. Who can help me?

Comment: check browser console for errors, most likely its not working because `ck` is not present in the json.

Comment: in offical website, ck is not present in the json

Comment: datagrid_data1.json is the reason, why i change this file name to datagrid.json, it works ok. Why this name datagrid_data1.json make result sometime different.

Comment: Wierd, [this demo](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid) is using datagrid_data1.json and it working fine.